# PHP Regex Allow numbers only with a specific length

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to create a preg_match test to allow numbers only. Definitely cannot use is_numeric or any variants.

Is this as safe as I can get?

```
/^\d*$/
```

And additionally, how would I set a min max range, for example check the number is between 6 and 10 digits?

Comment: What's wrong with `/^\d{6,10}$/`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well yeah, that's pretty safe. The regex does exactly that... allow only digits.

To specify a certain amount, here is the syntax:

```
/^\d{6,10}$/
```

However, since this is a **very** basic problem, you should probably check out [this site](http://www.regular-expressions.info).

Comment: Some people get regular expressions. Some don't. I'm the latter. Have read and reread regex documentation. Doesn't sink in.